# Oracle SQL Pivot with exclusions

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a set of data:

```
SELECT * FROM costings
```

Output:

```
section von         part    price
5       2013000043  3019    -15000
5       2014000041  1547    18000
5       2014000041  3019    -15000
5       2014000071  1547    18000
5       2014000071  3019    -15000
5       2016000018  1547    12000
5       2016000018  3019    -10000
5       2014000081  1549    3244.8
5       2014000081  3019    -1474
5       2015000040  1549    3244.8
5       2015000040  3019    -1474
5       2016000021  1549    2506.8
5       2016000021  3019    -1474
6       2013000069  1566    5760
6       2013000069  3013    -4800
6       2013000128  1566    7200
6       2013000128  3013    -6000
6       2014000060  1566    5760
```

And I want to output the data using pivot like this:

```
section 1547   1549   1566
5       -40000 -4422  null 
6       null   null   -10800
```

Now the logic behind the expected value amounts is that per `von` you have multiple `part` numbers.

So taking `2014000041` as an example this has `1547` & `3019`.

What i want is the `part` number beginning with `15` to be the pivot header but the `SUM` only to sum prices where the `part` DOESN'T begin with `15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the values that begin with "15", then one idea is to pre-aggregate along `section`/`von`, and then re-aggregate the results:

```
select section,
       sum(case when part15 = '1547' then price_not15 end) as part_1547,
       sum(case when part15 = '1549' then price_not15 end) as part_1549,
       sum(case when part15 = '1566' then price_not15 end) as part_1566
from (select section, von,
             max(case when part like '15%' then part end) as part15,
             sum(case when part not like '15%' then price end) as price_not15
      from costings
      group by section, von
     ) c
group by section;
```

This assumes that there is only one part that starts with `15` for each `section`/`von` combination.